# Is it possible to Launch Excel Interop application by double click on an icon that created by the installer

Tags: c#, deployment, build, excel-interop

I'm a newbie with Excel interop. We have a C# Excel Interop application. When the application launches, it automatically connects to DB using ODBC connection to fetch and load data into Excel worksheet (as an Excel com add-in is turned on after the app got installed).  This application currently launches every time Excel is started (when it's installed). I'm wondering, if possible to make it launches the same way as all other applications: User double click on an Icon and then the launching starts. (so that when user starts excel, they get their regular excel instead the application)

I've tried Changing output type from 'class library' to 'windows application.' But that did not work.

So I'm wondering what's the best approach, please?